# AngularCli App routes not working on Production

Tags: angular, routes, angular-cli, development-environment, production

I have an Angular app with AngularCli with the following routes configuration and NgModule. The Angular App will run on production mode inside an ASP.NET Core app

On app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { OneComponent } from './components/one.component';
import { TwoComponent } from './components/open/two.component';

const routes: Routes = [

  { path: '', redirectTo: 'one', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'one', component: OneComponent },
  { path: 'two', component: TwoComponent },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'one' }

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash:false })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

On app.module.ts

```
import { LocationStrategy, PathLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    OneComponent,
    TwoComponent    
  ]
  imports: [     
    AppRoutingModule,
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  providers: [{ provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: PathLocationStrategy }]
})
```

In development mode routes are OK, but when I go for production (ng build --prod --aot) the routes stop working.
If I use HashLocationStrategy routes work both development and production modes, but I have some problems because sometimes need to hit the Url two or three times when changing parameters on the url to connect with my Rest Api
The thing is that PathLocationStrategy gives me the behavior that I want but only on development and not in production.

I need a solution that works for both modes without issues

Any idea, thanks in advance

**Update:**
If you use ASP.NET Core 2.1+, no need to use URL rewrite, the project template for angular will handle this with the NuGetPackage Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices

Comment: how are you building and using app in development mode? like, using ng serve -o?

Comment: for dev  (ng serve) as usual. For deployment (ng build --prod --aot)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up fixing this problem with the same solution provided by Angular.io site 
[Go here](https://angular.io/guide/visual-studio-2015#for-apps-that-use-routing)

Need to add this to my asp.net core app web.config file:

```
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

The URL in `<action type="Rewrite" url="/"/>` should match the base href in index.html

Comment: how do i put this in my appsettings.json if thats the file i am using

Comment: I think you can do that by creating a class to parse appsettings.json. But if you are creating a new project just use the VisualStudio template for SPA Angular and all came with the SpaServices nuget package

Answer (score 0):

If you have deployed web app in IIS, try putting empty href tag and then build the app and deploy

```
<base href="">
```

Comment: I will give it a try

Comment: The problem persists

Answer (score 0):

What is the path to the Angular app on the server? If the initial URL for the index.html file is like "www.example.com/my/anular/app/", then in your your index.html you need to have `<base href="/my/angular/app/">`. Add option `--base-href /my/angular/app/` to `ng build`. The leading and trailing slashes are important.

Comment: Is an Asp.net Core Api app with a wwwroot folder containing my Single Page App. Angular project its separate from the Asp.net Core Api, but I make deploy to wwwroot folder on the  Asp.net Core Api